# ServerLike type in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I created a class in TypeScript (NodeJS) whose constructor has a param whose type is an Express app.

```
import type { Express } from 'express,'

class Hello {

  public constructor(server: Express){}
}
```

But I want to establish this type to like a `ServerLike` type which match any server created with anything and then use in the constructor the express() function to handle it with express.

The thing is that I don't know how to make the type or if is possible to do it though.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...match any server created with anything..."*?

Comment: In general, since TypeScript's type system is structural (based on the *shapes* of types) not nominal (based on the names/identities of types), if you want your `server` parameter to match anything with features X, Y, and Z, then just define `ServerLike` with those features. As long as those features are compatible with what you pass in, it will work. But I'm not sure if that's what you're asking.

Comment: But I don't know what properties they should share. Mmm . I could set the type as the type is set in the express function? This will work definitely, isn't it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean that I don't want to limit my class to only servers created with express I want to manage the server with express but inside my class then the user could put any type of server created with anything.

Comment: To what end, though, and how would it work? Rather than one class that can handle any "server", an approach that might be feasible is defining your own server-like interface, then having _different classes_ implement that interface to adapt between the various APIs and yours, e.g. `class ExpressServer implements GenericServer { ... }`.

Comment: My aim was to create a class which the user can use it. The user can create any server with any library or using native node but I want then to handle those different servers with express. I don't want to make mandatory create a server with express to use my package.

Comment: You need to implement the Adapter pattern. This means that you should define an `interface` named `ServerLike` that includes the type of all the functions that you are going to use in your app (e.g. listen, use, stop, etc.) you can also check the different servers such as express, koajs to get different ideas and the common patterns between them. After that, you can implement a class for each like so `class ExpressAdapter implements ServerLike { ... }`. There you implement the necessary methods and properties. Then you can pass the class to wherever that accepts it: `myFn(server: ServerLike)`

Comment: `Next Auth` library does the same thing you are planning to do (but it's for databases). You can check the source code to see how they implemented it or maybe even copy some of the codes. https://authjs.dev/getting-started/adapters